# Will duplicated geometry cause problems for 3D print it or WebGL?

Tags: mesh

I'm fairly new to blender. I want to design a somewhat complex model, that I can later print with a 3D printer and possibly use for WebGL as well. Before I start, I wanted to clearify that I'm actually joining the  meshes together properly and that overlapping and duplicate lines are acceptable.

I'm using the 'honeycomb' mesh that comes with blender as the base:

[image: honeycomb mesh]

I applied the array modifier to the mesh and set the X offset to 0.765 so it lines up properly:

[image]

From what I understand, the blender instead of 'extruding and copying' the honeycomb pattern, it 'stacked and copied' the pattern, in other words - the line that connects the original honeycomb mesh to the honeycomb copies is actually two lines overlapping each other at exact location.

In edit mode, if I 'click' once select and drag the points around, I can see there are duplicate lines:

[image]

Is there a function where Blender can remove this duplicate lines and recreate the mesh by 'joining' the points 'cleanly' and removing the duplicates so it's connected cleanly like the original honeycomb mesh?

My question is: Will this kind of mesh cause me any problems if I would want to 3D print it or use it for WebGL? is this considered bad design or is this mesh perfectly acceptable?

Another example, if I take 2 cubes, overlap them and ctrl+j(oin) them, is this a proper model, or do I need to redesign it, so there are no overlapping faces? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: In Edit mode `W` > *Remove Doubles* that's a pretty obvious one. You'd be advised to remove the duplicate faces before arraying though

Comment: You need to delete those points that will overlap if you are using an Array Modifier. To help visualize this remove the array modifier, select your mesh, duplicate it and drag it over until it lines up. You will see that those vertices will overlap...

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos not sure if I understood. The original honeycomb doesn't have any duplicates/overlapping lines, they are created by the array modifier and after applying the array modifier and 'Remove Duplicates' I get 'Removed 0 vertices' ( I selected all the points ctrl+a).

Comment: Array modifier has *Merge* and *First And Last* options designed specifically to solve the problems of overlappng duplicated geometry. Note that in general it's easier and more flexible just remove it in the first place to avoid the problem from the beginning, still it's possible. Remove Doubles doesn't necessary delete all the doubles at once; probably the vertices will be far enough to not fall under threshold of the operator.

Comment: @Dontwalk thanks! I understood the problem, but does that mean if I set array modifier count value to 100, I will have to edit the mesh manually and select/delete/re-join these overlapping lines 100 times? or did I misunderstood something

Comment: @MrZak thank you so much, that solved my issue! Please post it as answer and I will mark it, thanks!

Comment: I meant to remove the faces that will become overlapped before doing the array, like Mr Kak mentioned

Comment: You or anyone else are welcome to post the answer. Note that solution I proposed is fixing the problem which is better to avoid in general, so it might be not the best one (e.g. First And Last could remove more vertices than you expected). If posting answer add those details as well if possible